# Loop keeps running code inside even when condition is false

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

```
import datetime
from pydub.playback import play
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
times = [12, 19, 23] 
minutes = [53, 52, 51]
while True:
        for i in times:
            for j in minutes:
                if(currentDate.hour == i and currentDate.minute == j):
                    # print(os.getcwd())
                    index = minutes.index(j)+1;
                    print(index)
                    announce = AudioSegment.from_mp3(
                        f'{os.getcwd()}\\audios\\announcement_{index}.mp3')
                    play(announce)
```

This code keeps on playing "announce" even when the condition inside the if block is untrue can anyone please tell me what's the wrong logic i am applying in here.. any kind of help would be really helpful

"Times And Minutes both are lists"

Comment: Could you provide us with the times variable ?

Comment: sure

times = [12, 19, 23]
minutes = [53, 52, 51]

Comment: so edit your post to include that first.

Comment: umm ok i did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is that you are not updating the `CurrentDate` variable.
This results in an infinite loop if you are running the program when the condition is True.

So to solve that, you just have to update that variable :

```
times = [12, 19, 23] 
minutes = [53, 52, 51]
while True:
    # Updating the date every frame
    currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
            for i in times:
                for j in minutes:
                    if(currentDate.hour == i and currentDate.minute == j):
                        # print(os.getcwd())
                        index = minutes.index(j)+1;
                        print(index)
                    announce = AudioSegment.from_mp3(
                        f'{os.getcwd()}\\audios\\announcement_{index}.mp3')
                    play(announce)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because there is a `while True`. This means unless you `break` it, it will loop infinitely. I don't know why you wanted an infinite loop but this should solve the problem:

```py
import datetime
from pydub.playback import play
currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
times = [12, 19, 23] 
minutes = [53, 52, 51]

# no while loop here
for i in times:
    for j in minutes:
        if(currentDate.hour == i and currentDate.minute == j):
            # print(os.getcwd())
            index = minutes.index(j)+1;
            print(index)
            announce = AudioSegment.from_mp3(
                f'{os.getcwd()}\\audios\\announcement_{index}.mp3')
            play(announce)
```

Comment: Ah your problem is "announce is getting played infinitely". Then @Salem's answer is legit.

Comment: i am making an announcement system which check for time provided and current time matches the time given it announces that's why i need a forever loop to check the time at all times